# Snowflake SQL UDF returns "Unknown user-defined function" error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a query in Snowflake using SQL syntax. While it is mostly approachable, I am having issues creating a specific query. It appears Snowflake does not support nested SELECT statements and returns the error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated".

I would appreciate any feedback or input on how to go about solving this issue.

Here is logically how I intended the query to run:

```
create function demofunc(id varchar)
    returns table(
                  float,
                  float
    )
as
$$
    SELECT
      a.value1 as value1,
      func_other(id, a.value2) as value2 --where func_other returns a float and works fine
    FROM
      (
           SELECT
                     SUM(table1.value1) as value1,
                     table1.value2 as value2
           FROM      demotable table1
           WHERE
                     table1.id = id
           GROUP BY value2
      ) a
$$;
```

Running this yields "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated", so I tried to redo it using the suggestions on Snowflake docs as shown here, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-sql.html#troubleshooting, where they suggest separating everything out into their own functions, which still did not help.

```
create function func_1(id varchar)
    returns table(
            value1 float,
            value2 date
    )
as
$$
  SELECT
        SUM(table1.value1) as value1,
        table1.value2 as value2
  FROM demotable table1
  WHERE
       table1.id = id
  GROUP BY value2
$$;
----------------------------------------
create function func_2(id varchar)
    returns table(
            value1 float,
            value2 float
    )
as
$$
  SELECT
      a.value1 as value1,
      func_other(id, a.value2) as value2 --where func_other returns a float and works fine
  FROM
      TABLE(func_1(id)) a
$$;
----------------------------------------
select * from TABLE(func_2('AAAAA'))
```

Does anyone know of a good plan of attack or workaround? Thank you.

EDIT: I have added the other function, func_other below. It seems the initial subquery problem was due to me including a function call in the "WHERE" clause of my select statement in func_other. However, in trying to ameliorate this, I caused a new error where processing is simply aborted. As a result, I now get an execution error from Snowflake's side and am currently awaiting resolution.

To try and fix this, I select both values instead of trying to use a function call in the where clause, then call a separate function, step_func_other, instead of func_other, which simply selects one of the values that the new func_other returns. All of these work independently, but when combined into the master call (func2), execution breaks down.

old:

```
create function func_other(id varchar, value2 date)
    returns float
as
$$
    SELECT value3 as value3
    FROM table2
    WHERE
         p_id = id
         AND p_date = func_prev(id, value2)

$$;
```

where func_prev is defined as:

```
create function func_prev(id varchar, value2 date)
    returns date
as
$$
    SELECT 
         MAX(p_date) as p_date
    FROM 
         table2
    WHERE 
         p_id = id
         AND p_date < value2
$$;
```

new:

```
create function func_other(id varchar, value2 date)
    returns TABLE(value3 float, p_date date)
as
$$
    SELECT
        value3 as value3,
        func_prev(id, value2) as p_date
    FROM
        table2
    WHERE
        p_id = id
        AND p_date = p_date

$$;
-----------
create function step_func_other(id varchar, value2 date)
    returns float
as
$$
    SELECT
          CASE
              WHEN value2 IS NULL
                  THEN NULL
              ELSE value3
          END AS value3
    FROM
         TABLE(func_other(id, value2))
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you, Harsh. The `returns float` is indeed intended to be `returns table(float, float)`. However, this group of two functions continues to give me the `Unsupported subquery type` error.

Comment: I created these functions, also a table and dummy func_other to reproduce the issue, and they worked. I think you should share all SQL codes to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Very well, I have added the full sql code. There is nothing else executing now. @GokhanAtil

Comment: And @Harsh, would appreciate your thoughts as well. Thank you guys.